# New ESTA needed?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, esta

I am traveling to the US for a weekend in April.
I got an ESTA last year for a trip to Mexico because I had a connecting flight in the US. So on my ESTA it says “YES” for the question about it being for a transit. 
This ESTA is valid until June (as is my passport).

My questions are:

1. I cannot change the “travel information” and update the information with the US adress where I will stay for the weekend. Do I need to get a new ESTA? (Edit: others who had this problem the other way around (first visit, now transit) could change there adress into “transit”. Since I had no adress in my ESTA the first time, I cannot change it..)
2. Am I right that a passport doesn’t need to be valid for 6 months after travel to the US when traveling on an ESTA?

Comment: The fact that you're traveling on ESTA is not directly relevant to whether your passport needs to be valid for six months after you leave the US; rather, you need to see whether the country issuing your passport is on [the "six month club" list](https://www.cbp.gov/document/bulletins/six-month-club-update).  (In practice, I suppose that all VWP countries are probably on that list, but I haven't checked.)